# Why is $u^{1/2}=-5$ not a solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

\begin{align}
u+2u^{1/2}-15&=0\\
(u^{1/2}+5)(u^{1/2}-3)&=0\\
\end{align}

why is $u^{1/2}=-5$ not regarded as a solution, even though $(u^{1/2})^2=(-5)^2=(25)$? Is it because $\sqrt{u}$ can never be negative?

Comment: Yes, in $\Bbb R$, you are exactly correct.

Comment: If they ask for a solution of this then what they want is a value for $u$ that satisfies the equality (not a value for $u^{1/2}$).

Comment: You could have a solution in $p$-adics, though.  If you take the $3$-adic logarithm of $25$, divide by $2$ and exponentiate, you get $-5$.  Ditto if you carry over the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ into $3$-adics and thereby evaluate $\sqrt{1+24}$.

Comment: Even if you are working in $\mathbb C$ you have to define what $u^{\frac 12}$ means  There $K^2 = u$ there will be two such values.  If one of them is $(-5)$ then the other is $5$.  Is it correct to say $u^{\frac 12} =-5$ when we could also say $u^{\frac 12}=5$?

Comment: Note $-u^{\frac 12} = -5$ is a solution to $u - 2u^{\frac 12} - 15 = 0$.  You can factor that as $(-u^{\frac 12}+5)(-u^{\frac 12} - 3)$ but we can't have $-u^{\frac 12} = 3$ becuase we must have $-u^{\frac 12}$ be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

If $u^{\frac 12} = -5$ (which is *not* a conventionally acceptable definition)

The $u = 25$.

The $u + 2u^{\frac 12} -15 = $

$25 + 2*(25)^{\frac 12} - 15 = $

$25 + 2*5 - 15=$  (I'm sorry... if $25^{\frac 12}$ is supposed to have a *single* value it must be by convention the positive value)

$25 + 10-15 =20 \ne 0$.

Now had the question been:  Let $k$ be a number so that $k^2 = u$ then solve for $u$ where

$u + 2k - 15 = 0$

So $k^2 + 2k -15 = 0$

$(k+5)(k-3) = 0$

So $k=-5,3$ and $u =k^2 = 25,9$ would be fine.

Another way of putting that question would be:

Solve for $u$

$u + 2(\pm u^{\frac 12}) -15 = 0$

$(\pm u^{\frac 12} +5)(\pm u^{\frac 12} -3) =0$

So we have $\pm u^{\frac 12} = -5$ so $\pm = -$ and $-u^{\frac 12} = -5$ and $u =25$

Or $\pm u^{\frac 12} = 3$ so $\pm = +$ and $u^{\frac 12} = 3$ and $u=9$.

That's a weird way of looking at it but it works.

$u \pm 2 u^{\frac 12} -15$ has solutions whent $u =25$ and the $\pm $ is minus.  And when $u = 3$ and the $\pm$ is positive.